# Looping through an XML document and assigning data in C# variables

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file that has several tags like this:

```
<sitecollection name="">
  <site name="">
    <maingroup name=""> 
       <group name=""> </group>
    </maingroup> 
   </site>
<sitecollection>
```

The idea is to loop through all the `sitecollection` and it's child elements in the XML document, and save the info in variables. The problem I'm having is saving the child elements, with their attributes.

So far I have the following code:

```
class xmlreader
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("xmldocument.xml");
        var result = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        var lv1s = from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("sitecollection")
                   select new
                   {
                       siecollection = lv1.Attribute("name").Value,
                       maingroup = lv1.Descendants("group")

                   };
        foreach (var lv1 in lv1s)
        {
            result.AppendLine(lv1.siecollection);
            foreach (var lv2 in lv1.maingroup)
                result.AppendLine("   " + lv2.Attribute("name").Value);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem you are having? Not sure what your issue is.

Comment: The code you've shared doesn't include anything that would save the XmlDocument. Was that part omitted?

Comment: Well the code is not finished... I'm trying to read the xml document and print the results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sample XML you provided is accurate, the problem is likely that you don't have a closing tag for sitecollection.

I tried your code with a slightly varied XML input (closed the sitecollection tag, and added some values to the name attributes so there would be something to collect in the result StringBuilder) as follows:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<sitecollection name=""collectionName"">
    <site name=""sitename"">
    <maingroup name=""maingroupname""> 
    <group name=""groupname""> </group>
    </maingroup> 
    </site>
    </sitecollection>
    ");
```

and result.ToString() produces:  "collectionName\r\n   groupname\r\n"

Comment: Sorry. The correct sample would have </sitecollection> and they would be under a <root></root> element.

Answer (score 0):

Take this where you will:

```
  XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\file.xml", null);
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  while (reader.Read())
  {            
      if( reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
      {
          if (reader.HasAttributes) 
          {
              result.AppendLine(reader.LocalName);
              reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
              result.AppendLine("  " + reader.Value);                    
          }
       }                      
    }
```