# LINQ to read XML file and print results

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I got the following XML file (Data.xml):

```
<root>
 <sitecollection name="1A">
   <site name="1B">
     <maingroup name="1C"> 
        <group name="1D"> </group>
     </maingroup> 
    </site>
 </sitecollection>
 <sitecollection name="2A">
   <site name="2B">
     <maingroup name="2C"> 
        <group name="2D"> </group>
     </maingroup> 
    </site>
 </sitecollection>
</root>
```

And I need to print all the all the child elements in this format:

```
1A
 1B
  1C
   1D
2A
 2B
  2C
   2D
```

I have the following code so far which needs some adjustment. I could also change it completely if there's an easier method. Thanks for your help

```
class xmlreader
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        // Xdocument to read XML file
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");
        var result = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        var lv1s = from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("sitecollection")
                   select new
                   {
                       sitecollection = lv1.Attribute("name").Value,
                       maingroup = lv1.Descendants("group")

                   };
        var lv2s = from lv2 in xdoc.Descendants("site")
                   select new
                   {
                       site = lv2.Attribute("name").Value,
                       sitetittle = lv2.Descendants()
                   };
        var lv3s = from lv3 in xdoc.Descendants("maingroup")
                   select new
                   {
                       maingroup = lv3.Attribute("name").Value,
                   };
        var lv4s = from lv4 in xdoc.Descendants("group")
                   select new
                   {
                       grouppage = lv4.Attribute("name").Value,
                   };


        // Loop to print results
        foreach (var lv1 in lv1s)
        {
            result.AppendLine(lv1.sitecollection);
            foreach (var lv2 in lv2s)
            {
                result.AppendLine("   " + lv2.Attribute("name").Value);

                foreach (var lv3 in lv3s)
                {
                    result.AppendLine("   " + lv3.Attribute("name").Value);

                    foreach (var lv4 in lv4s)
                    {
                        result.AppendLine("   " + lv4.Attribute("name").Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looping through an XML document and assigning data in C# variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658947/looping-through-an-xml-document-and-assigning-data-in-c-sharp-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With such a uniform hierarchy, recursion can do the job with a lot less code:

```
    void PrintNames(StringBuilder result, string indent, XElement el)
    {
        var attr = el.Attributes("name");
        if (attr != null)
        {
            result.Append(indent);
            result.Append(attr.Value);
            result.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
        }
        indent = indent + " ";
        foreach(var child in el.Elements())
        {
            PrintNames(result, indent, child);
        }
    }

...

var sb = new StringBuilder();
PrintNames(sb, String.Empty, xdoc.Root);
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I want to execute a different code depending on the child element? For example, for the first one I just want to print it, and for the other ones I need to execute some kind of code snippet.

Comment: @Mark-AR Then you should probably post a different question. :P  If the action is dependent upon the element name, you can put in a switch statement to break out logic per element name where the attr code is now.  If the action is dependent on the element's position in the hierarchy (do A if element is FOO and element.Parent is GREEN) and doesn't follow a uniform pattern then I probably wouldn't use single-function recursion. Single-function recursion is most efficient when the action to be performed is uniform across the tree.

Comment: @Mark-AR If you want to perform different actions based on an elements location in the tree (who its parents are or what their attributes are), I might set up multiple functions which are called as more specific information is discovered as we traverse the tree. Basically, a recursive descent parser.

Comment: @Mark-AR If the differentiator for the actions you want to perform is simply the depth in the tree (root = 0, children = 1, grandchildren = 2) then you could add a depth counter parameter to the recursive function and then test the depth value to decide what action to perform.  Pass in zero on the initial call, and increment it once per generation.  Similar to how the indent is expanded for each recursion level in the sample code above.

Comment: I wish I could see a code sample.. I'm very new in programming so it's hard to apply what you mention without a visual guide. If a ask a new question would you mind helping me out with a code sample? Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: I posted a rephrased question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683445/reading-xml-and-performing-an-action-depending-on-the-attribute I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following, find all elements with a name attribute, then add spaces based on their depth.

```
var result = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
var namedElements = doc.Descendants().Where(el => el.Attributes("name")!=null);
foreach(var el in namedElements)
{
  int depth = el.Ancestors().Count();
  for (int i=0;i<depth;i++)
    result.Append(" "); 

  result.Append(el.Attributes("name").Value);
  result.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
}
```

NOTE: The above is from memory, so please check the syntax!

Comment: Just wanted to throw in a comment that instead of: `for (int i=0;i<depth;i++)
    result.Append(" "); ` you could instead just use `result.Append(string.format("{0," + depth + "}", ""));`